# How to achieve supersampling / anti-aliasing in pixel shaders?

Tags: c#, wpf, hlsl, antialiasing, pixel-shader

I am trying to write a couple pixel shaders to apply to images similar to Photoshop effects. For example this effect:
http://www.geeks3d.com/20110428/shader-library-swirl-post-processing-filter-in-glsl/

But I noticed there is aliasing in the resulting image. What can I do to prevent this? I couldn't find any article that explains how to solve this. I read some techniques like rendering in high res and then downsizing the image, but I need to solve this in a pixel shader capacity. But if there is something that could help, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score -2):

The [WPF Shader Effect Library](http://wpffx.codeplex.com/) already has that same exact effect, along with many others. You can download the source from the link.

Comment: Thanks I will check it out. But are you sure they handle aliasing? Because all shaders I found online wasn't doing anything for this.

Comment: I have tried the effects and they look pretty cool. Im not really sure how they're made since I don't have much knowledge of shaders and so on.

Comment: Ok I just checked, they are the same, just doing a single texture lookup per pixel, which gives you these artifacts.